# Restore RDS instance with maintaining original backups

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We have the next script for restoring DB.

- Rename the current DB instance (mydb -> old_mydb).
- Restore a DB instance to a specific point in time in new DB instance. Restore old_mydb to mydb.

But after restoring the new DB instance doesn't have old backups and we can't restore this instance again. Are there any ways to link the old backups to the new instance?

Comment: No. Restoration creates new database.

Comment: Why would you even do that?

Comment: Sometimes, after incorrect migrations, we need to rollback the database. And it seems to be the fastest way.